# How to combine initialization and assignment of dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to figure out if any deal is selected twice or more.

The following example is stripped down for sake of readability. But in essence I thought the best solution would be using a dictionary, and whenever any deal-container (e.g. deal_pot_1) contains the same deal twice or more, I would capture it as an error.

The following code served me well, however by itself it throws an exception...

```
    if deal_pot_1:
       duplicates[deal_pot_1.pk] += 1

    if deal_pot_2:
        duplicates[deal_pot_2.pk] += 1

    if deal_pot_3:
        duplicates[deal_pot_3.pk] += 1
```

...if I didn't initialize this before hand like the following.

```
    if deal_pot_1:
       duplicates[deal_pot_1.pk] = 0

    if deal_pot_2:
        duplicates[deal_pot_2.pk] = 0

    if deal_pot_3:
        duplicates[deal_pot_3.pk] = 0
```

Is there anyway to simplify/combine this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two options:

1. Use a `collections.defaultdict(int)`.  Upon access of an unknown key, it will initialise the correposnding value to 0.
2. For a dictionary `d`, you can do

   ```
   d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1
   ```

   to initialise and increment in a single statement.

**Edit**: A third option is `collections.Counter`, as pointed out by Mark Byers.

Comment: Couldnt get teh first one working, but the second one worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).  It looks like you want `defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

So you only want to know if there are duplicated values? Then you could use a [set](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
duplicates = set()
for value in values:
    if value in duplicates():
        raise Exception('Duplicate!')
    duplicates.add(value)
```

If you would like to find all duplicated:

```
maybe_duplicates = set()
confirmed_duplicates = set()

for value in values:
    if value in maybe_duplicates():
        confirmed_duplicates.add(value)
    else:
        maybe_duplicates.add(value)

if confirmed_duplicates:
    raise Exception('Duplicates: ' + ', '.join(map(str, confirmed_duplicates)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A set is probably the way to go here - collections.defaultdict is probably more than you need.

Don't forget to come up with a canonical order for your hands - like sort the cards from least to greatest, by suit and face value.  Otherwise you might not detect some duplicates.